# I rigged a human model with Inversed Kinematics but it is not working. How can I debug this?

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics

I'm having a hard time understanding how to debug my rig not working. I created the human model and now I am trying to rig the right leg.

How could share more information about this?

I would like my rig to behave this way: https://youtu.be/SBYb1YmaOMY?t=443

[image: This is what I see]

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/d9lXpgeP

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how it is not working. Is your rig not animating the object, or is your IK constraint not working.

Comment: yes we lack informations, also you should share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you both for replying!

Comment: I added my file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/d9lXpgeP

Comment: I'd like it to behave like this: https://youtu.be/SBYb1YmaOMY?t=443

Answer (score 2):

Just unparent the IK control in **Edit mode**. Now it will work.

Change the LowerLeg pole angle to 0. Your pole is inversed like a chicken leg.

In **Edit Mode** select the foot and uncheck Inherit Rotation. This will make the foot return to the right position.

[image]

Just in case an animated gif:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The only thing, in the three steps I couldn't do is "unparent the IK control in Edit mode". Could you tell me how I can do that please?

Comment: Done. If this answer is the solution, You could mark it as the right answer.